# Can a servo be made to oscillate within n degrees of its angle position

Tags: servo, pid-controller

If I want to be able to give a servo a certain angle and also have it oscillate +/- n degrees  of that angle (maybe even at some frequency f), how would I be able to do it with code? This is for a remote-desktop-controlled cat toy.

Comment: Servo is a broad term. But, you probably want a servo that accepts a digital 50 Hz signal where the duty cycle specifies the position. Then, use an MCU timer to create this signal. Then vary the timer duty cycle.

Comment: You would simply keep adjusting the angle.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to pic a microcontroller or a hobby board such as Arduino or Nano and write a program for it. Find one that has a library for the servo actuator and that will look after most of the complicated stuff. You'll find sample code with the library and then you'll have to add something like this.

Pseudo code

```
    setup(){
      min = 108;    // On scale of 0 - 255.
      max = 157;    // On same scale.
      posn = min;   // Start position.
      step = 1;     // 1 = increase. -1 = decrease.
    }

    main(){
      while (1 = 1) {   // Loop forever.
        posn += step;   // Add the step value to the position.
        if (posn > max) {
          step = -1;    // Start counting down.
        }
        if (posn < min) {
          step = 1;     // Start counting up.
        }
        servoOut(posn);  // Send the signal to the servo actuator.
        delay(3);           // Set delay between steps here.
      }
    }
```

Have fun!